# Encrypting messages sent to a WCF services hosted on a server with real IP

Tags: .net, wcf, security, wcf-security

I have a WCF Service hosted on a server with Real IP but no domain name. Clients are .NET desktop applications.
I need to encrypt the data going back and force between the clients and the server.
How can I do that? I understand that Certificates required for the SSL connection need a domain name. is this accurate? What options do I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your clients are .NET applications consider using NetTcpBinding which is secure by default. All message packets are signed and encrypted over TCP protocol.

You can also control protection level on message contracts providing granular control over specific headers or body elements.

You can use [ProtectionLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347692.aspx) property. 
Options are: `None`, `Sign`, and `EncryptAndSign`.

- None disables message protection.
- EncryptAndSign provides full message
  protection and is the default
  behavior.
- Sign indicates the message should be
  signed but not encrypted

WCF gives you rich security features, for more details check [Windows Communication Foundation Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732362.aspx)

Comment: how likely is it to face firewall issues if I use netTcpBinding comparing to wsHttpBinding? or there is no difference?

Comment: You can set TCP port as an exception in the firewall rules.